# Cannot display api data in ejs template

Tags: node.js, json, ejs

I can retrieve the api data and console.log it and the for loop is displaying each  card div element correctly but I cannot get the details to display for each item.

plant.js controller:

```
exports.postFindPlant = async (req, res) => {
    const plantName = req.body.searchPlant;
    const key = process.env.API_KEY;
    const urlAPI = `https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants/search?token=${key}&q=${plantName}`;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(urlAPI);
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.meta.total === 0) {
            console.log('nada');
        } else {
            console.log(data.meta.total);
            let plants = JSON.stringify(data);
            res.render('plants', {
                plants: plants,
                pageTitle: 'Plants',
                path: '/plants',
                hasPlants: plants.length > 0
              });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

plants.ejs:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < plants.length; i++) { %>
            <div class="col s12 m4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                          <img class="activator" src="<%= plants[i].image_url %>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                          <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"><%= plants[i].common_name %><i class="material-icons right">MORE</i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><%= plants[i].common_name %><i class="material-icons right">CLOSE</i></span>
                          <p><%= plants[i].scientific_name %></p>
                          <p><a href="/plant-details/<%= plants[i].id %>">Plant Details</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <% } %>
```

Comment: Does `response.json()` return an **Object** in your controller code? Then you can't access it's values via index within your for loop unless it's an **Array**.

Comment: So, check `data` (result of the `response.json`)'s format, loop and select the data you want in correct way. Like instead of `plants[0].scientific_name`, maybe it should be `plants.data.scientific_name`? Remember `data` and `plants` are same variable but only after stringify in your code.

Comment: Hi Casimir, thanks for the help. Changing plants[i].scientific_name to plants.data.scientific_name throws a reference error. When I console.log(data) returns an obj with an array of objects

Comment: let plants = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(plants); returns `{"data":[{"id":132808,"common_name":"Centipede tongavine", ...`

Comment: I've post an answer to the question, which explains origin problem of the question you posted.

Comment: Thanks so much @CasimirCrystal! I will follow along to your answer. I'm still learning so this is a big help. Appreciate it!

Comment: And if you found my answer is useful, please accept it by clicking the check remark on the left side of an answer, which means it answers to your question. And good luck to your coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Node.js code, you get the data from API with:

```js
const data = await response.json();
```

Usually, some data returned from an API contains much information with keys, so it could be an **Object**. (I guessed, but confirmed in comments)

And then, if you want to access any info from an Object, you have to refer the value by it's key. For example:

```js
> const person = { name: "Alan", age: 20 }
undefined
> person.name
'Alan'
> person.age
20
```

But if it's a object which contains an Array, and you want to access the Array's data, you can use Array index **after refer the Array with it's key in the Object.**

```js
> const person = { name: "Alan", age: 20 }
undefined
> const person2 = { name: "Alice", age: 18 }
undefined
> const people = { type: "Human", data: [person, person2] }
undefined
> people
{
  type: 'Human',
  data: [ { name: 'Alan', age: 20 }, { name: 'Alice', age: 18 } ]
}
>
```

For example, how to get `Alice` in my code above?

```js
> people.data
[ { name: 'Alan', age: 20 }, { name: 'Alice', age: 18 } ]
> people.data[1]
{ name: 'Alice', age: 18 }
> people.data[1].name
'Alice'
>
```

In your case, you parse the Object to JSON, and passed it into your Ejs code. It's still an Object, so I assume you know how to refer the values you want with correct keys in `plants.ejs`, and the things you need is only `plants.data`. Then, just change this line of your `plant.js` controller below:

```js
let plants = JSON.stringify(data);
```

To something like:

```js
let plants = JSON.stringify(data).data;
```

What makes the different? Take a look again to my examples above, this refer to `people.data`, which is an Array of Objects, instead of ***an Object** which contains an Array of Objects.*

So hope you have fully understand what is the problem, and how to solve it.

Comment: BTW, if your code still doesn't work, hold it, read the API's document, **try to get the data with your token *in the nodejs console***. Then you copy the way of "how did you get the correct data you need" from the console to ejs code, and make the job done.